# variable not getting invoked in azure powershell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set a variable in a release pipeline in azure-devops as `myFlag : true`.
I tried to invoke `myFlag` in a powershell task but am not getting any result. My inline script:

```
If ( $myFlag -eq 'false' ) {
  Write-Host "Hit!"
} Else {
  Write-Host "Not Hit!"
}
```

$myFlag is not having any value and hence else block is getting hit.

Comment: Can you provide the yaml of where it is coming from and how you're then passing it to the powershell task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If ( $myFlag -eq 'false' )

The caused reason of no value in `$myFlag` is this is a definition format of dynamic variable which just exists in current job. In one world, it is creating a new variable named `myFlag` rather than getting the value from **the variable you pre-defined**. That's why no value in `$myFlag`.

According to your logic of script, you are getting value of `myFlag` which pre-defined in Variables tab, then compare it with "`false`". If the value of myFlag is False, print out `Hit!` in log, otherwise print `Not Hit!`. So, just change your script as:

```
If ('$(myFlag)' -eq 'false' ) {
  Write-Host "Hit!"
} Else {
  Write-Host "Not Hit!"
}
```

Or:

```
$myFlag = '$(myFlag)'

If ($myFlag -eq 'false') {
  Write-Host "Hit!"
} Else {
  Write-Host "Not Hit!"
}
```